# Why assembly addition doesn't work if the result is over 9?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I am following a basic tutorial from here:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_arithmetic_instructions.htm

And the default code from here:
https://www.jdoodle.com/compile-assembler-nasm-online

```
section .text

global _start

_start:

    mov     eax, [x]
    sub     eax, '0'
    mov     ebx, [y]
    sub     ebx, '0'
    add     eax, ebx
    add     eax, '0'

    mov     [sum], eax

    mov     ecx, msg
    mov     edx, len
    mov     ebx, 1
    mov     eax, 4
    int     0x80

    mov     ecx, sum
    mov     edx, 1
    mov     ebx, 1
    mov     eax, 4
    int     0x80

    mov     eax, 1
    int     0x80

section .data
    x db '5'
    y db '3'
    msg db  "sum of x and y is "
    len equ $ - msg

segment .bss

    sum resb 1
```

But once the result is over 9 it refuses to print the result or prints some character (like > ;)

Comment: The example doesn't even try to work for results that would be more than 1 decimal digit, so I have to conclude that it isn't meant to work

Comment: same result with sum resb 10, and mov edx,10

Comment: The method you used only works for single digits. Also, your code is wrong because it's using 4 byte accesses to 1 byte variables.